# How to access to google drive and create/edit table fusion with app phoneGap

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, google-maps-api-3, sencha-touch-2

please if somebody can help me to find a way to develop a function that allow me, through my app phoneGap (and sencha) to access to my google drive's account and create my own tables (google fusion table); i found one file javascript :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
  Copyright 2011 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.

  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
  you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
  You may obtain a copy of the License at

      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License.
-->
<html>
  <head>
    <title>JavaScript API Example</title>

    <style type="text/css">
      body { font-family: Arial; }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      // The clientId and apiKey are available at
      // https://code.google.com/apis/console. For more information, see
      // http://code.google.com/p/google-api-javascript-client/wiki/Authentication.
      var clientId = '958693490238-nti7k45ajor0287286o8a5p4m26um32n.apps.googleusercontent.com';
      var clientSecret = 'p--MYTDoaqliiiSmP4TPFZX5';
      var apiKey = 'AIzaSyCa_oJyC4vX1KAbNoi0n0Zyqf_ZWTp8J7U';
      var scopes = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fusiontables';
      var tableId;

      // Initialize the client, set onclick listeners.
      function initialize() {
        gapi.client.setApiKey(apiKey);
        document.getElementById('create-table').onclick = createTable;
        document.getElementById('insert-data').onclick = insertData;
        document.getElementById('select-data').onclick = selectData;
        window.setTimeout(function() { auth(true); }, 1);
      }

      // Run OAuth 2.0 authorization.
      function auth(immediate) {
        gapi.auth.authorize({
          client_id: clientId,
          client_secret: clientSecret,
          scope: scopes,
          immediate: immediate
        }, handleAuthResult);
      }

      // Handle the results of the OAuth 2.0 flow.
      function handleAuthResult(authResult) {
        var authorizeButton = document.getElementById('authorize-button');
        var createTableButton = document.getElementById('create-table');
        if (authResult) {
          authorizeButton.disabled = true;
          createTableButton.disabled = false;
        } else {
          authorizeButton.disabled = false;
          authorizeButton.onclick = function() { auth(false); return false; };
        }
      }

      // Run a request to create a new Fusion Table.
      function createTable() {
        var tableResource = [];
        tableResource.push('{');
        tableResource.push('"name": "People",');
        tableResource.push('"columns": [');
        tableResource.push('{ "name": "Name", "type": "STRING" },');
        tableResource.push('{ "name": "Age", "type": "NUMBER" }');
        tableResource.push('],')
        tableResource.push('"isExportable": true');
        tableResource.push('}');
        runClientRequest({
          path: '/fusiontables/v1/tables',
          body: tableResource.join(''),
          method: 'POST'
        }, function(resp) {
          var output = JSON.stringify(resp);
          document.getElementById('create-table-output').innerHTML = output;
          tableId = resp['tableId'];
          document.getElementById('table-id-1').innerHTML = tableId;
          document.getElementById('table-id-2').innerHTML = tableId;
          document.getElementById('insert-data').disabled = false;
          document.getElementById('select-data').disabled = false;
          document.getElementById('create-table').disabled = true;
        });
      }

      // Run a request to INSERT data.
      function insertData() {
        var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
        var age = document.getElementById('age').value;
        var insert = [];
        insert.push('INSERT INTO ');
        insert.push(tableId);
        insert.push(' (Name, Age) VALUES (');
        insert.push("'" + name + "', ");
        insert.push(age);
        insert.push(')');
        query(insert.join(''));
      }

      // Run a request to SELECT data.
      function selectData() {
        query('SELECT * FROM ' + tableId);
      }

      // Send an SQL query to Fusion Tables.
      function query(query) {
        var lowerCaseQuery = query.toLowerCase();
        var path = '/fusiontables/v1/query';
        var callback = function(element) {
          return function(resp) {
            var output = JSON.stringify(resp);
            document.getElementById(element).innerHTML = output;
          };
        }
        if (lowerCaseQuery.indexOf('select') != 0 &&
            lowerCaseQuery.indexOf('show') != 0 &&
            lowerCaseQuery.indexOf('describe') != 0) {

          var body = 'sql=' + encodeURIComponent(query);
          runClientRequest({
            path: path,
            body: body,
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
              'Content-Length': body.length
            },
            method: 'POST'
          }, callback('insert-data-output'));

        } else {
          runClientRequest({
            path: path,
            params: { 'sql': query }
          }, callback('select-data-output'));
        }
      }

      // Execute the client request.
      function runClientRequest(request, callback) {
        var restRequest = gapi.client.request(request);
        restRequest.execute(callback);
      }
    </script>
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=initialize"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>
      Fusion Tables JavaScript Example
    </h1>
    <h2>
      (1) Authorize using OAuth 2.0
    </h2>
    <p>
      Click Authorize to start the OAuth 2.0 authorization flow. If you have
      already authorized, the button will be disabled.
    </p>
    <input type="button" id="authorize-button" value="Authorize"><br>

    <h2>
      (2) Create Table
    </h2>
    <p>
      Click "Create Table" to create an exportable Fusion Table called "People"
      with columns "Name" with type "STRING" and "Age" with type "NUMBER".
      <pre>
{
  "name": "People",
  "columns": [
    {
      "name": "Name",
      "type": "STRING"
    }, {
      "name": "Age",
      "type": "NUMBER"
    }
  ],
  "isExportable": true
}</pre>
    </p>
    <input type="button" id="create-table" value="Create Table"
        disabled="disabled">
    <p id="create-table-output"><i>table response goes here...</i></p><br>

    <h2>
      (3) Insert data
    </h2>
    <p>
      Insert data into the newly created table.
    </p>
    <pre>INSERT INTO <span id="table-id-1">[table_id]</span> (Name, Age) VALUES ([name], [age])</pre>
    <label>Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="name"><br>
    <label>Age:</label>
    <input type="age" id="age"><br>
    <input type="button" id="insert-data" value="Insert data"
        disabled="disabled">
    <p id="insert-data-output"><i>insert response goes here...</i></p><br>

    <h2>
      (4) Select all the rows from the table
    </h2>
    <p>
      Select the data that has been inserted into the newly created table.
    </p>
    <pre>SELECT * FROM <span id="table-id-2">[table_id]</span></pre>
    <input type="button" id="select-data" value="Select data"
        disabled="disabled">
    <p id="select-data-output"><i>select response goes here...</i></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

then i integrate it in my app sencha (in localhost) with my own client id and apiKey, and it work , but when i deployed it into my device android it does nooooot :( i understund that my device does'nt detect the account's informations ( my account gmail is active in the device but the page of authorization doesn't appear).

please some help !!